# Is it undefined behavior to do runtime borrow management with the help of raw pointers in Rust?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, ffi, borrowing

As part of binding a C API to Rust, I have a mutable reference `ph: &mut Ph`, a struct `struct EnsureValidContext<'a> { ph: &'a mut Ph }`, and some methods:

```
impl Ph {
    pub fn print(&mut self, s: &str) {
        /*...*/
    }
    pub fn with_context<F, R>(&mut self, ctx: &Context, f: F) -> Result<R, InvalidContextError>
    where
        F: Fn(EnsureValidContext) -> R,
    {
        /*...*/
    }
    /* some others */
}

impl<'a> EnsureValidContext<'a> {
    pub fn print(&mut self, s: &str) {
        self.ph.print(s)
    }
    pub fn close(self) {}
    /* some others */
}
```

I don't control these. I can only use these.

Now, the closure API is nice if you want the compiler to force you to think about performance (and the tradeoffs you have to make between performance and the behaviour you want. Context validation is *expensive*). However, let's say you just don't care about that and want it to just work.

I was thinking of making a wrapper that handles it for you:

```
enum ValidPh<'a> {
    Ph(&'a mut Ph),
    Valid(*mut Ph, EnsureValidContext<'a>),
    Poisoned,
}

impl<'a> ValidPh<'a> {
    pub fn print(&mut self) {
        /* whatever the case, just call .print() on the inner object */
    }
    pub fn set_context(&mut self, ctx: &Context) {
        /*...*/
    }
    pub fn close(&mut self) {
        /*...*/
    }
    /* some others */
}
```

This would work by, whenever necessary, checking if we're a `Ph` or a `Valid`, and if we're a `Ph` we'd upgrade to a `Valid` by going:

```
fn upgrade(&mut self) {
    if let Ph(_) = self { // don't call mem::replace unless we need to
        if let Ph(ph) = mem::replace(self, Poisoned) {
            let ptr = ph as *mut _;
            let evc = ph.with_context(ph.get_context(), |evc| evc);
            *self = Valid(ptr, evc);
        }
    }
}
```

Downgrading is different for each method, as it has to call the target method, but here's an example `close`:

```
pub fn close(&mut self) {
    if let Valid(_, _) = self {
        /* ok */
    } else {
        self.upgrade()
    }
    if let Valid(ptr, evc) = mem::replace(self, Invalid) {
        evc.close(); // consume the evc, dropping the borrow.

        // we can now use our original borrow, but since we don't have it anymore, bring it back using our trusty ptr
        *self = unsafe { Ph(&mut *ptr) };
    } else {
        // this can only happen due to a bug in our code
        unreachable!();
    }
}
```

You get to use a `ValidPh` like:

```
/* given a &mut vph */
vph.print("hello world!");
if vph.set_context(ctx) {
    vph.print("closing existing context");
    vph.close();
}
vph.print("opening new context");
vph.open("context_name");
vph.print("printing in new context");
```

Without `vph`, you'd have to juggle `&mut Ph` and `EnsureValidContext` around on your own. While the Rust compiler makes this trivial (just follow the errors), you may want to let the library handle it automatically for you. Otherwise you might end up just calling the very expensive `with_context` for every operation, regardless of whether the operation can invalidate the context or not.

Note that this code is rough pseudocode. I haven't compiled or tested it yet.

One might argue I need an `UnsafeCell` or a `RefCell` or some other `Cell`. However, from reading [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34496) it appears `UnsafeCell` is only a lang item because of *interior mutability* — it's only necessary if you're mutating state through an `&T`, while in this case I have `&mut T` all the way.

However, my reading may be flawed. Does this code invoke UB?

(Full code of `Ph` and `EnsureValidContext`, including FFI bits, available [here](https://bitbucket.org/SoniEx2/hexchat-plugin.rs).)

Comment: As someone who's curious but way out of their field, is there a simple reason why `someValid.upgrade()` would panic rather than simply doing nothing?

Comment: @BHustus there are a lot of reasons why that code shouldn't really ever panic, the main one being that I was tired. thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3):

Taking a step back, the guarantees upheld by Rust are:

- `&T` is a reference to `T` which is potentially aliased,
- `&mut T` is a reference to `T` which is guaranteed not to be aliased.

The crux of the question therefore is: what does *guaranteed not to be aliased* means?

---

Let's consider a safe Rust sample:

```
struct Foo(u32);

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self) { self.bar(); }
    fn bar(&mut self) { *self.0 += 1; }
}

fn main() { Foo(0).foo(); }
```

If we take a peek at the stack when `Foo::bar` is being executed, we'll see at least two pointers to `Foo`: one in `bar` and one in `foo`, and there may be further copies on the stack or in other registers.

So, clearly, there *are* aliases in existence. How come! It's guaranteed NOT to be aliased!

---

Take a deep breath: how many of those aliases can you *access* at the time?

Only **1**. **The guarantee of no aliasing is not spatial but temporal.**

I would think, therefore, that at any point in time, if a `&mut T` is accessible, then *no other reference* to this instance must be accessible.

Having a raw pointer (`*mut T`) is perfectly fine, it requires `unsafe` to access; however forming a second reference may or may not be safe, even without using it, so I would avoid it.

Comment: I think the application of the term "aliasing" to situations where references are used in non-overlapping fashion represents a corruption of the term by the authors of gcc.  Hopefully Rust avoids such idiocy.

Answer (score 2):

Rust's memory model is not rigorously defined yet, so it's hard to say for sure, but I believe it's not [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) to:

1. carry a `*mut Ph` around while a `&'a mut Ph` is also reachable from another path, so long as you **don't dereference** the `*mut Ph`, even just for reading, and don't convert it to a `&Ph` or `&mut Ph`, because mutable references grant *exclusive access* to the pointee.
2. cast the `*mut Ph` back to a `&'a mut Ph` once the other `&'a mut Ph` falls out of scope.