# How to create UnsafeCell<c_void> safely?

Tags: rust, unsafe

The `UnsafeCell` [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) says

> The `UnsafeCell<T>` type is the only legal way to obtain aliasable data that is considered mutable.

The only construction method is:

```
pub const fn new(value: T) -> UnsafeCell<T>
```

However, it is not possible to create a `c_void`, we can only create `*mut c_void` or `*const c_void`.

Is it possible to create `UnsafeCell<c_void>` from a `*mut c_void`? With this, we can let the compiler know that the pointer can point to something mutable.

Or is this not necessary? Can we always use `*mut c_void` even we know some FFI call will mutate the data it points to and we have multiple references to it?

A use case would be:

```
struct FFIStruct { v: UnsafeCell<c_void>, other_fields: ... }
impl FFIStruct {
    // We don't want to require &mut self, as we 
    // are sure private call_ffi() will always be called 
    // sequentially, and we don't want to stop
    // status() being callable during the call
    fn call_ffi(&self){ ffi_function(self.v.get()) }
    pub fn status(&self) -> FFIStatus { ... }
}
```

Now how do we create `FFIStruct`? Or just use `*mut c_void` would be OK?

## Example code to create `&Cell<c_void>`

Requires `#![feature(as_cell)]`:

```
unsafe fn get_cell<'a>(p: *mut c_void) -> &'a Cell<c_void> {
    Cell::from_mut(&mut *p)
}
```

Comment: Do you actually access `v` in your code, or is it opaque? If it's opaque, all of this is not necessary.

Comment: It is opaque and only the FFI implementation can touch it.  But can you be more specific to say what is not necessary? Do you mean the use of `UnsafeCell`? or `*mut c_void` (which I think would be necessory...)

Comment: `UnsafeCell` informs the Rust compiler that a value may change at any time, even though the compiler can see a shared reference to it. This is important for when the compiler wants to use the value, so that it knows it can't just hold it in a register. But if the compiler never touches the field, because it's only touched by FFI functions, then the annotation isn't necessary.

Comment: of course you can't what is the size of void ?

Comment: @Stargateur `UnsafeCell` does not require `Sized`, so we can put DST in it...

Comment: I'm not very aware of these concept in Rust, but I don't think it's possible to create a thing that hold void, whatever Rust magic feature have. That the entire point of void in C. You can't write `void a;`, you can only have `void *a;`. And this make sense because void is... nothing. You can't do anything to `*a` because it's a void type. Someone have to know what is its real type to use it. So I don't know how Rust would be capable of this.

Comment: A dynamically-sized type (DST) is not the same as an *unsized* / *zero-sized* type.

Comment: `void` is not allowed as a value in C, so why do you expect to have one in Rust?

Comment: I think you want an `UnsafeCell<*mut c_void>`. A mutable pointer to data of an unknown type, that may be mutated by other code during the existence of the pointer.

Comment: @Shepmaster If `c_void` is fully uninhabited it is like `UnsafeCell<!>`, but in reality although `c_void` is uninhabited but `*mut c_void` is not: it will point to an opaque value. What I expecting is to express the fact that this opaque value can be modified/changed even we have a shared reference to the object owns it.

Comment: @Phoenix The semantic is quite different though. `UnsafeCell<*mut c_void>` contains additional abstraction: it is a pointer to a pointer. This also means the `get` method is not ready to be sent to FFI without `unsafe` deference.

Comment: *a pointer to a pointer* — why do you believe that? I think that may be the root of your issue.

Comment: @Shepmaster because, we can only get `*mut T` from `UnsafeCell`, which makes it work like a pointer. And the fact it supports DST also implies it is an indirection (means pointer, maybe I was wrong here?). So if we use a pointer as the contained value it will be a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @EarthEngine it would help if you could edit the question to be about the actual, high-level problem you are trying to solve. What happened here is that you want part-way down the *wrong* rabbit-hole, got stuck, and are asking a very specific question that is already making some wrong assumptions. So I suggest you take a couple steps back and focus on what you want to achieve: Which kind of API do you want to wrap, which kind of operations does it provide, what do the user-visible types look like in C, what would you like the user-visible types to look like in Rust?

Comment: But to literally answer your question, remember that `UnsafeCell` is NOT a pointer, so it seems what you want is a `*mut UnsafeCell<c_void>`, which you can obtain from `*mut c_void` by a simple cast. That's even a safe operation. It's not at all what you want though.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Just use `*mut Foo`. Cells of any kind are *not* needed here.

---

**Disclaimer: there is no formal Rust memory model, yet.**

You *cannot* create this type, period, because you cannot<sup>1</sup> create an instance of `c_void`.

The thing is, you don't *need* to create such a type. [Aliasing is not spatial but temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49513368/155423). You can have multiple `*mut T` pointing to the same place and it doesn't matter *until you try to access one*. This essentially converts it to a reference and the aliasing requirements need to be upheld while that reference is around.

> raw pointers fall outside of Rust's safe memory model.
>
> — [*The Rustonomicon*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/ffi.html#calling-foreign-functions)

> Different from references and smart pointers, raw pointers:
>
> - Are allowed to ignore the borrowing rules by having both immutable and mutable pointers or multiple mutable pointers to the same location
> - Aren’t guaranteed to point to valid memory
> - Are allowed to be null
> - Don’t implement any automatic cleanup
>
> ¸— [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#dereferencing-a-raw-pointer)

See also:

- [Why does modifying a mutable reference's value through a raw pointer not violate Rust's aliasing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52548161/155423)
- [What's the Rust idiom to define a field pointing to a C opaque pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315383/155423)
- [Is it undefined behavior to do runtime borrow management with the help of raw pointers in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49503331/155423)
- [Can an FFI function modify a variable that wasn't declared mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47620011/155423)

<sup>1</sup> You technically *can*, but that's only because of an implementation and backwards compatibility limitation.

Comment: This is what I thought. However, `UnsafeCell` was refered to as "the root of interior mutability", and this example seems to imply that, `*mut T` is another root. Am I right? (Maybe I should open another question...)

Comment: @EarthEngine Interior mutability means you can mutate something while only holding a shared reference (`&T`) to it. Raw pointers don't let you do that. Mutating something through a `*mut T` isn't interior mutability, that's just regular mutability.

Comment: I know. But when you look at my `FFIStruct` example, I wanted to hide the fact that `self.v` can be mutated while only holding a shared reference `&self` to it. Is this interior mutability? Also, please check my example for `&Cell<c_void>`.

Comment: @EarthEngine `self.v` **must not** be mutated by FFI code because the pointer itself is accessed as an immutable reference (via `&self`). The value that `self.v` **points to** can be mutated because it's behind a raw pointer.

Comment: @Shepmaster Just a simple question: Do `FFIStruct` has interior mutability? How many level behind the pointers does not matter: they are all owned by the struct, conceptually.

Comment: @EarthEngine I honestly cannot answer that question — I have no idea ^_^

Comment: @EarthEngine Interior mutability is not a concern for you *until you create a shared reference to some data*. And I mean directly to that data, not transitively through a raw pointer. So I think every single mention of `UnsafeCell` and interior mutability in this discussion is a red herring. You never have a shared ref to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

After [some internal discussion in the Rust forum](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/ffi-mutating-raw-pointer-where-immutable-reference-in-scope-is-this-ub/8510/3) and [a discussion on RFC 1861](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43467), I realize `c_void` is just a common workaround and other options exists like `struct Opaque<UnsafeCell<()>>`.

So I concluded what I needed here is `*const UnsafeCell<c_void>`. From its type we know:

- This is a raw pointer, so it is suitable to send to FFI immediately;
- The raw pointer assumes `const`, means any casting to `*mut T` will UB and programmer should avoid it. This protects the memory it points to being modified within Rust (unless through `UnsafeCell`, of cause);
- It contains `UnsafeCell`, so it implies interior mutability. This justifies the FFI function being able to mutate it;
- It is not possible to create a `c_void`, so as for `UnsafeCell<c_void>`. They can only be created by FFI.

[Demostrate](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=62448cb6f4aa82dbe7d9e6014175d09a&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
use std::os::raw::c_void;

//Let's say all those functions are in an FFI module,
//with the exact same behaviour
fn ffi_create() -> *mut c_void {
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(0u8)) as *mut c_void
}
unsafe fn ffi_write_u8(p: *mut c_void, v:u8) {
    *(p as *mut u8) = v;
}
unsafe fn ffi_read_u8(p: *mut c_void) -> u8 {
    *(p as *mut u8)
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        //let's ignore ffi_destroy() for now
        let pointer = ffi_create() as *const UnsafeCell<c_void>;
        let ref_pointer = &pointer;        
        ffi_write_u8((&*pointer).get(), 7);
        let integer = ffi_read_u8((&**ref_pointer).get());
        assert_eq!(integer, 7);
    }
}
```

It is interesting how easy and ergonomic (yet expressive) to convert between `*mut c_void` and `*const UnsafeCell<c_void>`.

Comment: I don't think this is the type you want. I am afraid your question was already somewhat ill-posed, which is why the answers also became confusing. The thing is, UnsafeCell is only relevant for shared references. If you do FFI and *everything is behind a ptr indirection*, then you do not have to worry about `UnsafeCell`. Just use `*mut` and wrap it in a newtype. [The nomicon has some further information](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/ffi.html#representing-opaque-structs).